# How to display a field in user meta in default WordPress registration form

Tags: wordpress

I have a requirement where I wish to show a field `office_name` in WordPress default registration form.

What I did so far: I have created a field called 'office_name' by using the following code:

```
function my_show_extra_profile_fields() {
$user_contact_method['office_name'] = 'name of your office';
$user_contact_method['office_location'] = 'location of your office';
return $user_contact_method;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
```

The `office_name` field is appearing in the USERS tab in the back end and getting updated when I enter the values there.

I want it to appear in the registration form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your registration form . Here is the Wordpress codex link.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form